# Reactjs is showing the blank page in IE 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, package.json

React code is showing blank page in internet explorer,but working fine in chrome and safari.
Tried adding:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; 
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import "core-js/stable";
```

in the index.js.

Please find the attached screenshot of the error in IE console
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1A1s.png)

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sampleapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.0.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "3.4.5",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.3",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-aria-menubutton": "^6.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
    "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
    "react-icons-kit": "^1.0.7",
    "react-intl": "2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.3",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.0-rc.3",
    "reselect": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.json",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "ie >= 9"
  ],
}
```

and .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["react","env","es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; 
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from 'history';
import App from './Containers/App';
import "./index.css" 
import 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./.htaccess'; // eslint-disable-line import/extensions
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import './global-styles';

const initialState = {};
const history = createHistory();
const store = configureStore(initialState,history);
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept(['./i18n', '../src/Containers/App'], () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
    render();
  });
}

render();
```

App is created using create-react-app. Can you help me finding the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide full information. Like Version of compilers. Full code of index.js. What are showed in Developer conole?

Comment: By the way, you are using an old package of babel polyfill, now it is called `@babel/polyfill`.

Comment: IE is very strict in tags openings and closings. Make sure to check the tags (specifically body tag as mentioned in the console error)

Comment: @TemaTre, I updated the question with index.js file

Comment: The issue got resolved. Problem was with the react-scripts, I changed the version to 3.2.0.